# Siri: Reminder Tied to Multiple Locations

Tags: iphone, siri

I've been wondering if there is a good workaround to solve the following problem with Siri.

There are some stores in my area that have multiple locations, for example Walmart.  I have added Walmart as a contact in Siri, along with the two addresses.  However, every time I ask Siri for something like, "Remind me to pickup X while at Walmart", she always asks me to pick a particular address.  Is there a way to create the reminder tied to BOTH addresses?

My current workaround is to create two reminders, one for each location, but that is far from ideal.

I'd like to expand this to cover other categories, such as "Grocery Store", "Home Improvement Store",  etc, but creating multiple reminders quickly becomes too much of a hassle to manage.

Comment: Not to be a pessimist, but I'd be surprised if you can do something like what you described. It is an interesting question, and I think it would be great if it was possible, but chances are, the best you might get is a 3rd party app - which effectively eliminates your using Siri to create reminders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that but the reminders only work for *one* location each. You may be able to achieve the effect of using multiple geofences (the underlying technology) using a third-party program (e.g. [Checkmark](http://www.builtbysnowman.com/checkmark/)) but I have not tried that myself. Integration with Siri is not possible at the moment of this reply (no Siri API for third party developers available).